# Add iframe to xml for a flash website

Tags: xml, iframe

I need to add an iframe so it loads up an outside website in my flash site. The site uses xml files for all the text. The site I am referring to is tripodoregon.com click on The Scoop.

Any help is much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0):

flash doesnt use iFrames.
iframes are html tags, flash isnt an html renderer